# how to create html page in visual studio to use bootstrap framework

Tags: sharepoint-server, html

I downloaded bootstrap framework using this [link](https://responsivesharepoint.codeplex.com/releases/view/112845) available on codeplex.

I have created empty sharepoint project in visual studio 2013. Then manually added bootstrap related files in Layout folder. See my project files in visual studio below

[image]

Now i want to add my own html page which can use bootstrap framework. Where exactly i can add it and how will it use bootstrap framework

Comment: You should probably use `.aspx` pages and not `html`pages in SharePoint!

Comment: @RobertLindgren But why cant i use html page? is there any restriction? Sorry i am new so really dont know

Comment: SharePoint is built on ASP.net and hence uses .aspx pages to display it's content. Using html pages would just be a dirty workaround

Comment: @RobertLindgren but can you tell me using both aspx and html pages.

Comment: @RobertLindgren any solution you have yet?

Comment: No one has any solution to this problem? Please do help